# Sum 2 rows in SQL with join

Tags: sql, join, sum, left-join, union-all

I want to join 2 tables and get sum of 2 rows:

Table A

```
barcode product store sold
---------------------------
AA       Tea     1    200
AA       Tea     2    300
BB       Milk    3    100
```

Table B

```
warehouse  barcode   product    stock   
--------------------------------------
WH1          AA      Tea        1000
WH2          AA      Tea         200
WH3          BB      Milk        500
```

Expected result:

```
store   barcode   product  sold    stock
----------------------------------------
1          AA       Tea     200     1200
2          AA       Tea     300     1200
3          BB       Milk    100      500
```

Any idea how to get this?

Comment: what is the logic... you need to explain more.

Comment: also pls tag you dbms.

Comment: A subquery would do this - something like this:


select store, barcode, product, sold, stock = (select sum(stock) from b where a.product = b.product and a.barcode = b.barcode)
from a

Answer (score 1):

Presumably:

```
select a.store, a.barcode, a.product, a.sold,
    (select sum(b.stock) from tableb b where b.barcode = a.barcode) as stock
from tablea a
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider table A as table_A and table B as table_B
below is the query.

```
select A.store, A.barcode , A.product, A.sold, X.stock from table_a as A
inner join
(
select barcode, sum(stock) as stock from table_B
group by barcode
) as X
on A.barcode = X.barcode
```